# Is $n(n+1)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(n+1)}$ solvable?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve

$$y = n(n+1)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(n+1)}$$

where

$$n,y\in\mathbb{C}$$

$$\Re(n)>1$$

$$\Re(y)>0$$

I need to find $n$ for every $y$. MATLAB cannot solve this symbolically and its numerical solution has local minimums.

If this cannot be solved, what is the best way to solve it numerically?

Comment: See the comments under https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473890/how-to-explicitly-express-one-variable-as-a-function-of-an-other-one

Comment: So, $n$ is a complex number.  Not necessarily an integer?  In that case, NO, there is no solution in commonly used functions.

Comment: You can simplify into $x(x-1)e^{ix}$ or use [Lagrange Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) to find a series solution. However, you would need to find the $n$th derivative of $\left(\frac{1}{(x-1)e^{ix}}\right)^{n+1}$ or  $\left(\frac{(x+1)}{(x-1)xe^{ix}-2e^{-i}}\right)^{n+1}$ if the first one fails