# How to explicitly express one variable as a function of an other one

Tags: real-analysis

I need to represent the variable $V$ as a function of T and then find $(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_{P=const}$ in the following expression, $$P=\frac{Te^2}{2V-1}e^{-\frac{2}{TV}}. $$

Taking the logarithm at both sides did not help much.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: This is an example of a trascendental equation. Some of them can be solved using the Lambert W function, but it's not the case with this one, so it's not possible to solve this equation.

Comment: We can't solve equations like $xe^x = 3$ without inventing new functions.  Your equation is like this but more complicated.  So the answer to your question is "no."

Comment: Pressure, Volume, and Temperature of a fluid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above, it's not easy (or even possible) to get $V$ in function of $T$ and $P$.

But as your question involves the derivative of $V$ with respect to $T$, we can treat $P$ constant and can get the implicit derivative.
Rewriting this equation we get

$$
\exp\left(-\dfrac{2}{TV}\right) = \dfrac{P}{e^2} \cdot \dfrac{2V-1}{T}
$$

Derivating both sides with respect to $T$

$$
\exp\left(-\dfrac{2}{TV}\right) \cdot \left[\dfrac{2}{(TV)^2} \cdot \left(V + T\dfrac{dV}{dT}\right)\right] = \dfrac{P}{e^2} \left[\dfrac{2\frac{dV}{dT} - (2V-1)}{T^2}\right]
$$

We now isolate $dV/dT$ to get

$$
\left[\dfrac{T}{V^2}\exp\left(-\dfrac{2}{TV}\right) - \dfrac{P}{e^2}\right] \cdot \dfrac{dV}{dT} = \dfrac{P}{e^2}\cdot \dfrac{1-2V}{2} - \dfrac{1}{V} \exp\left(-\dfrac{2}{TV}\right)
$$

Using the first equation to get rid of the exponential

$$
\dfrac{dV}{dT} = \dfrac{V(2V-1)(TV+2)}{2T(TV^2-2V+1)}
$$

As we can see, the derivative only depends on $T$ and $V$.

If we do the same for $P$ we can compute

$$
\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial P} = \dfrac{TV^2(1-2V)}{2P(TV^2-2V+1)}
$$

**Numerical problem**

If you know the values of $T$ and $V$, you can compute the derivative easily.
But if you only know $P$ and $T$, I suggest using an algorithm to find $V$ using the first equation and then applying to the derivative.

As an estimative to find $V$ we can see that

$$
0 < \exp\left(\dfrac{-2}{TV}\right) \le 1 \ \ \ \forall \ T, V \in \mathbb{R}^{+}
$$

$$
0 < \dfrac{P}{e^2} \cdot \dfrac{2V-1}{T} \le 1
$$

$$
\dfrac{1}{2} < V \le \dfrac{1}{2} \left(1 + e^2 \cdot \dfrac{T}{P}\right)
$$

And then using the bisection method or Newton's method with starting point at

$$
V_0 = \dfrac{1}{4} \left(2 + e^2 \dfrac{T}{P}\right)
$$

EDIT: The newton's method estimates successively the values like

$$
x_{i+1} = x_{i} - \dfrac{f(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}
$$

In this problem, we want to find a good estimative for $V$ with known $P$ and $T$. So, we want to find the solution to the equation

$$
h(V) = \dfrac{P}{e^2} \cdot \dfrac{2V-1}{T} - \exp\left(\dfrac{-2}{TV}\right)
$$

So we get

$$
\dfrac{d h}{d V} = \dfrac{2}{T}\left(\dfrac{P}{e^2}-\dfrac{1}{V^2}\exp\left(\dfrac{-2}{VT}\right)\right)
$$

And therefore we make the successive computations

$$
V_{i+1} = V_{i} - \dfrac{h\left(V_{i}\right)}{\dfrac{dh}{dV}\left(V_{i}\right)}
$$

```
# Results with $P=200$ and $T=400$
 vmin =  0.5
 vmax =  7.8890560989306495
   V0 =  4.194528049465324
h(V0) = -0.4988086809643937
   V1 =  7.887999953247512
h(V1) =  0.000490739612107105
   V2 =  7.884371697705249
h(V2) =  1.340453303910749e-10
   V3 =  7.884371696714192
h(V3) =  1.1102230246251565e-16
```

```
# Results with $P=400$ and $T=200$
 vmin =  0.5
 vmax =  2.347264024732662
   V0 =  1.423632012366331
h(V0) = -0.4930003255279375
   V1 =  2.342651561599207
h(V1) =  0.0017626534217525247
   V2 =  2.339384525356445
h(V2) =  8.260528483461371e-09
   V3 =  2.339384510045608
h(V3) = -2.220446049250313e-16
```

```
# Results with $P=0.3$ and $T=0.3$
 vmin = 0.5
 vmax =  4.194528049465324
   V0 =  2.347264024732662
h(V0) =  0.4998006718932871
   V1 =  0.49578703027447313
h(V1) = -0.0011403269021434156
   V2 =  0.5000000000000019
h(V2) = -4.248354255292223e-18
   V3 =  0.5000000000000019
h(V3) = -4.248354255292223e-18
```

Comment: Many thanks. I am wondering why in the implicit derivative $P$ disappears whereas in the numerical approach $P$ 'survives'. I actually need $P$ to be there. Is there maybe a mistake in computing the implicit derivative ?

Comment: I verified with ```python``` and ```sympy``` to compute the algebraic expression, and it's indeed correct. The $P$ disappears because it's constant when we take the partial derivative with respect to $T$. But remember that $V$ depends on the value of $P$. So, if you change slightly $P$, it will change also $V$ and the value of $dV/dT$ is not the same anymore.

Comment: That's right but my concern is in the consistency of both approaches. In the numerical approach, once you have an expression for $V$, $\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}$ will still depend on $P$ which is not the case in the implicite derivative approach.

Comment: I don't get it. How do you have an expression for $V$? And the implicit derivative has the term $P$ inside $V$. As we found, $\partial V/\partial T = f(V, T)$ and $V$ is in fact $V(P, T)$ that means there's a function $g(P, T)$(unknown, hard to find it) such that $\partial V/\partial T = f(V(P, T), T) = g(P, T)$.

Comment: By the expression of $V$ i meant $V_0$ above. Is $V_0$ not meant to be an approximation of $V$ we were looking for ? $V_0$ then explicitly depends on $P.$

Comment: I added some examples in the answer. $V_0$ is meant only to be the starting point to use a numerical method. Not an approximation. When we use the Newton's method, we see the initial value $V_0$ is not good but $V_{2}$ (computed with $V_1$ which was computed with $V_0$) is good.